# Validate cell data with empty cells

Tags: excel, validation

I want to create cells where only 2 values can be put: "x" or "" (empty cell). I want the users to be able to put the values either by hand (type "x" from keyboard or use backspace to clear the cell) or using the dropdown list (which includes only mentioned 2 values).

But Excel doesn't want to let me do this.

The only way to create a dropdown list I know is to use "Data Validation" and choose "List" as the type. For my list to contain an empty cell I have to use a named range as the source.

And that all works fine except there's really no validation - user can type any value to the cell and there's no error.

To force actual validation I have to uncheck "Ignore blank" option. And that almost does the trick except now the user cannot type the values manually - there are errors even if the user provides correct data!

Is there any way to make Excel actually do what it's supposed to?

Edit: It's really reprehensible that something so basic cannot be done straightforwardly and requires dirty hacks instead.

Edit2: Perhaps there are differences between Excel versions. I use MS Office 365 ProPlus. I didn't specify that in my questions intentionally as I wanted a version-agnostic solution. But perhaps there isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

How have you tried it? You can use a few things for your list:

`x,=char(1)` or `x,=" "`, work for me:

[image]

Comment: That actually almost works. Well, completely works but I want the dropdown list to show empty line instead of "=char(1)" string. Is there a way to make it so?

Comment: @NPS I'll try. Are you able to use a macro? Or no VBA?

Comment: I'd rather avoid macros.

Comment: @BruceWayne apologies for the side discussion... excellent demonstration of your results. What tools are you using to generate this gif?

Comment: @nbayly - No worries! It's a program called ["GifCam"](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/). It's a very lightweight program and pretty simple to use :D

Comment: @NPS - At the risk of sounding like I'm avoiding your question, which I'm not!, If you can get the listbox to show `x` and a blank line, while you can't successfully use `BACKSPACE` (as you noted), you can use `DELETE`. Perhaps you can just note that to the user?  With VBA, you could use a `Worksheet_Change()` event to make sure it's set to empty...I'm having trouble finding a way to get `x` and a blank row in the drop down *while* allowing the user to just use `BACKSPACE` to clear the data...this is trickier than I thought!

Comment: Yes, I noticed that Delete and pasting data seems to bypass validation entirely. But you know how it is - users just want to do it any way they want and any limitation (like using Delete instead of Backspace) is criticized. But anyway, I don't understand why Excel is fine with typing "x" manually but recognizes Backspace (so empty cell) as something different than option from dropdown list (which is also empty cell)...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - I am unable to comment on the BruceWayne reply, so post this as an answer.

If you are able to reference cells for your data validation then have one cell with x as its value and another cell with ' as its value. Select these two cells as your list Source in data validation. The blank value will then be visible and selectable in the drop-down list.

Comment: With "Ignore blank" on I have no validation (can put in any value). With "Ignore blank" off I cannot clear the cell manually (with backspace).

Comment: I cannot replicate this. With "Ignore blank" on I can only have a blank cell or an x. I can also clear the cell manually with backspace. To be clear, the second cell the the validation sources is not blank - it has value '

Comment: One thought - did you check that show error alert tab has been selected with a stop option?

Comment: Stop is the default (unless I don't understand what you're asking about). And it's weird that you get different behavior than I do - with "Ignore blank" on I can type anything into the cell, press enter (or otherwise leave the cell) and don't get any errors.

Comment: I tried various options. When I implement the validation with a blank cell then it acts as you wish it to. When I implement the validation with a value in the cell then I cannot remove blank values. But for certain, when I start with a blank cell and put the validation on as described it works as you request. Strange we get different output with the same commands.

Comment: I just found out: if I list possible values for the cell (`x;'`) I get validation with "Ignore blank" on! But when I use named range instead I get no validation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your target cell is `A1` then on that cell you would place a custom Data Validation with the following formula:

```
=OR(A1="x",A1="")
```

This will validate only if "x" or empty cell is inserted as a value. Will reject all other values. Regards,

Comment: I need the dropdown list as well.